# New ubuntu install need to clean second disk

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partition, hard-disk

I have installed Ubuntu on my old laptop to give him a second life. I installed Ubuntu on the 24gb SSD. But the old Windows10 partition is on the 1tb HDD.

Now every time I boot the system it asks which one I want to boot from. I dont want this, and want to just delete everything from this disk (the Windows one ofcourse) and start with a clean disk. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open `gnome-disks`, or `gparted`.
I recommend `gparted`.
Execute `sudo apt install gparted`, if you don't have it installed.
Select the drive you want to clean in the upper right corner, and press `Device` -> `Create partition table`.   [image: selecting type]
You would usually pick `msdos` type as it is readable by all modern OSes.
Now your disk is clean, you may create new partitions of any type. Ubuntu is familiar with ext4 or btrfs. I recommend the latter if you'd like to use snapshot functionality (restore backed-up file states).

Comment: @sudodus it will be `msdos` type, unless you want 3TB+ partitions, then pick `gpt`

Comment: If newer UEFI system better to use gpt. Some minor advantages over MBR even on smaller drives. You must use gpt if drive is over 2TiB. MBR is now over 35 years old.  See answer by Rod Smith (author of gdisk). https://askubuntu.com/questions/629470/gpt-vs-mbr-why-not-mbr